# How to train a neural network to learn a "function" that maps from high-dimensional space(~300d) to 2D plane?

Tags: neural-network, dimensionality-reduction

Now，I have aobut 10M data points in 300 dimensional space, waiting for reducing into 2D space. I know some dimension reduction algorithms, such as t-SNE, multi-core t-SNE, Q-SNE, umap, largevis. However, they are too slow for such a big scale of data. I think the following idea may mitigate the problem:

1. simple 10% data, applying a DR algorithm to get (300d, 2d) pair for each data, treating these pairs as training data.
2. use the training data to train a deep neural network that caputers the mapping from 300d to 2d
3. apply the learned mapping to the rest of 90% data.

Is this a feasible idea? Do you know any work following the similar idea? Any suggestions for building such a neural network?

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for are autoencoders.

[image: Autoencoder]

You train this neural network in a way that the output vector is the closest possible to the input vector (you may need to try several distance losses: euclidean distance, TripletSemiHardLoss, ...). In this way, the hidden layer with two neurons will be your 2D representation!
In any case, your approach is smart too, maybe just a bit more laborious.